# Why is the 'find' query returning a Query object in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have already looked at many answers here at SO, but none of them solved my problem.

I'm currently creating a project using node, express, and mongodb. I started with a seeder file to put some data into mongodb:

```
var products = [
    new ProductModel(data),
    new ProductModel(data),
    new ProductModel(data),
    new ProductModel(data),
];

// Connecting to mongodb using mongoose.
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb.dsn, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB through Mongoose.");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error when connecting to MongoDB through Mongoose: " + error);
    });

// Saving product instances to the product document in mongodb
var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].save((error, result) => {
        done++;
        if (done == products.length) {
            // Disconnecting...
            console.log("All products have been loaded into mongodb. Disconnecting now...");
            mongoose.disconnect();
        }
    });
}
```

Then, I am trying to retrieve this data in my routes file, using:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const products = ProductModel.find();
    console.log(products);
    res.render('shop/index', { products });
});
```

However, I am console.logging the result on my terminal, and the only result that comes up is a query object that looks like this:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection { 
(...)
_traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true }
```

I needed to retrieve the products in my db. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because `find()` is an `async` op. Either use callback to get results or use `.exec()` to turn it get fully-fledged promise. [**Mongoose Model.find()**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is executed as it should. `find()` returns a `Query` object as per the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

If you want it to return the value, just turn it to an await and call `exec` to get a promise:

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    const products = await ProductModel.find().exec();
    console.log(products);
    res.render('shop/index', { products });
});
```

Comment: @ambianBeing Thanks I wasn't 100% sure on that.